# Regular expression 30 numbers + space + hypen + space+ 1 number

Tags: java, regex

I have this code to find this pattern: 201409250200131738007947036000 - 1 ,inside the text

```
              final String patternStr = "(\\d{30} - \\d{1})";
              final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);


                  final Matcher m = p.matcher(page);
                  if (m.matches()) {
                      System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                  }
```

But for any strange reasson in Java did't work, Can somebody help me where is the error please?

Comment: Are you trying to find that pattern _inside_ text of check whether an entire `String` matches that pattern? You also don't need to parenthesis.

Comment: Why to use Pattern-Matcher when you can use `String.matches` ?
By the way ur code is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the `matches` method checks for the entire given string to match the regex.

So i.e. if your string is `123456123412345612341234561234 - 8` it will match, if it is `my number 123456123412345612341234561234 - 8 is inside other text` it won't.

Use the `find` method to accomplish your task:

```
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
}
```

It will *search inside* the given string instead of attempting to match the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for `Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), `matches`:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

As opposed to `find` which:

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

So use `matches` to match an *entire* `String` against a pattern, use `find` to locate a pattern inside a `String`.

Try:

```
final String patternStr = "\\d{30}+\\s-\\s\\d";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

final Matcher m = p.matcher(page);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("FOUND A MATCH: %s%n", matcher.group());
}
```

I edited your pattern slightly to make it more robust. This will print *each* match that it finds.